# Assigning texture to material in Blender 2.9

Tags: texturing

I just downloaded Blender 2.9 and tried to create a material for an object.  I wanted to assign a texture to the Base Color slot of the default material, so I clicked on the dot on the right side in the property window.  However, instead of getting a drop down menu of material options like in older versions, the dot just changes to a diamond and back again.

I can't find anything in the docs explaining how to assign textures.  I did notice that the 2.9 docs are calling the textures 'legacy textures'.  What's going on?  Can I still assign a texture?  Do I have to set up a shading network if I want to use textures?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The little dot on the right side of the Base Color slot is for keyframing. You can click the yellow dot on the left side of the color to get the drop down menu for textures.

[image: Add texture]

If you click the actual color panel you can choose the base color.

[image: Add color]